# Dynamically generate JSON index with array sign

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I generate the JSON index dynamically using Javascript/ReactJS? I need to develop this type of JSON data:-

```
{
    portfolioId[0]: "Dhaka",
    portfolioId[1]: "Chittagong",
    portfolioId[2]: "Sylhet",
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is `portfolioId`, and what should the final output look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the index. If you mean the dynamic key for your Json you can use this syntax:

```
{
    [portfolioId[0]]: "Dhaka",
    [portfolioId[1]]: "Chittagong",
    [portfolioId[2]]: "Sylhet",
}
```

The `[` and `]` will make it as dynamic.

For example:

```
let hello = 'bye'
{
    [hello]: 'world'
}
```

will result:

```
{
    'bye': 'world'
}
```

Comment: Hi @R10t, sure, I marked the answer with an upvote.